# ruby: can't add a new key into hash during iteration

Tags: ruby

I have three hashes:

```
db_headers = {"1"=>"first_name", "2"=>"last_name"}
csv_headers = {"1"=>"First Name", "2"=>"Last Name"}
csv_records = {"0"=>{"id"=>"11", "first_name"=>"first_0", "Last Name"=>"last_0", "created_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"12", "first_name"=>"first_1", "Last Name"=>"last_1", "created_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC"}}
```

db_headers and csv_headers are matched by their keys. For example, their key "2" values contain "last_name" and "Last Name" respectively. My goal is wherever the values are different between db_headers and csv_headers where the keys are the same, then I need to swap the key in csv_records with value of db_headers. So for example, csv_records key will change from "Last Name" to "last_name", since db_headers and csv_headers value at key "2" were different.

This is what I came up with:

```
  csv_records.each do |record_key,record_value|
    csv_headers.each do |csv_key,csv_value|
      if record_value.has_key? csv_value
          db_headers.each do |db_key, db_value|
            if csv_key == db_key
              csv_records[db_value] = csv_records.delete csv_value
              break
            end
          end
          break
      end
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately it fails:

```
RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration
    from (irb):12:in `[]='
    from (irb):12:in `block (3 levels) in irb_binding'
    from (irb):10:in `each'
    from (irb):10:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
    from (irb):8:in `each'
    from (irb):8:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):7:in `each'
    from (irb):7
```

This made the error go away:

```
csv_records.keys.each do |record_key|
    csv_headers.keys.each do |csv_key|
      if csv_records[record_key].has_key? csv_headers[csv_key]
          db_headers.keys.each do |db_key|
            if csv_key == db_key
              csv_records[db_headers[db_key]] = csv_records.delete csv_headers[csv_key]
              # break is needed becasue csv_key wont exist in next iteration
              break
            end
          end
      end
    end
  end
```

But csv_records is supposed to now have a value last_name, but it continues to have "Last Name" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have major memory constraints, use `reduce` to build up your desired records.

```
# If you need to keep csv_headers and db_headers for another reason, you can use them to create REPLACE_KEYS.
REPLACE_KEYS = {"First Name"=>"first_name", "Last Name"=>"last_name"}
csv_records = {"0"=>{"id"=>"11", "first_name"=>"first_0", "Last Name"=>"last_0", "created_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"12", "first_name"=>"first_1", "Last Name"=>"last_1", "created_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC"}}    

def transform_record(record)
  record.reduce({}) do |acc, (key, value)|
    new_key = REPLACE_KEYS[key] || key
    acc[new_key] = value
    acc
  end
end

db_records = csv_records.reduce({}) do |acc, (row, record)|
  acc[row] = transform_record(record)
  acc
end
```

Comment: I found this to be useful

Answer (score 7):

Iterate on `hash.keys` instead of on `hash`. `#keys` will make an array that is separate from the hash, so you won't be messing up the iteration as you modify the hash.

Comment: If I iterate on hash keys, how am I supposed to retrieve the hash value?

Comment: `hash[key]`...? Retrieving a value when you only have a key is the core functionality of a hash.

Comment: This doesn't address the actual bug in the code. Please see my solution. There is no need to iterate on hash.keys.

Comment: @ClaytonC: This is correct; I was offering the standard way of dealing with that particular runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your code.  You are trying to modify the wrong hash (which is easy to do when you have nested hashes).  So:

```
csv_records[db_value] = csv_records.delete csv_value
```

should instead be:

```
record_value[db_value] = record_value.delete csv_value
```

That alone should fix your problem.

Also, as a further tip, it seems that you could combine the csv_headers and db_headers hashes into one hash:

```
{ "First Name" => "first_name",
"Last Name" => "last_name" }
```

Which should allow you to simplify the logic of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- select the keys that are in all three hashes
- of those keys, select the ones that have different values in `db_headers` and `csv_headers`
- for those keys, swap the values in `db_headers` and `csv_headers`

Converting this approach to code is straightforward:

```
(csv_records.keys & db_headers.keys & csv_headers.keys).select { |k|
  db_headers[k] != csv_headers[k] }.each { |k|
    db_headers[k], csv_headers[k] = csv_headers[k], db_headers[k] }

db_headers  #=> {"1"=>"First Name", "2"=>"last_name"}
csv_headers #=> {"1"=>"first_name", "2"=>"Last Name"}
```

We have

```
keys = csv_records.keys & db_headers.keys & csv_headers.keys
  #=> ["1"]

selected_keys = keys.select { |k| db_headers[k] != csv_headers[k] }
  #=> ["1"]
```

Then perform a parallel assignment for each of these keys (here just one):

```
selected_keys.each { |k|
  db_headers[k], csv_headers[k] = csv_headers[k], db_headers[k] }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the replacing rules from db_headers  and csv_headers

```
map = Hash[db_headers.merge(csv_headers){|_,v1,v2| [v2,v1]}.values]
#=> {"First Name"=>"first_name", "Last Name"=>"last_name"}
```

Then with tap to transfer data in csv_records :

```
csv_records.tap {|x| 
  map.each {|from,to| 
    x.each{|k,v| 
      x[k][to]=x[k][from] if x[k][from]
      x[k].delete(from) 
    }
  }
}
#=> {"0"=>{"id"=>"11", "first_name"=>"first_0", "created_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "last_name"=>"last_0"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"12", "first_name"=>"first_1", "created_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "updated_at"=>"2014-08-12 17:02:28 UTC", "last_name"=>"last_1"}}
```

Shorten in one line:

```
csv_records.tap {|x| map.each {|from,to| x.each{|k,v| x[k][to]=x[k].delete(from) if x[k][from] }}}
```

**UPDATE**

For your logic, the problem is:

- There's no need to iterate db_headers in cvs_headers's iteration, get the target db_hearder directly from the db_hearders hash.
- `csv_records.delete csv_headers[csv_key]` will do nothing, because csv_records only have keys of "0" and "1", you should use `csv_records[record_key].delete csv_headers[csv_key]`.

Try this:

```
csv_records.keys.each do |record_key|
  csv_headers.keys.each do |csv_key|
    if csv_records[record_key].has_key? csv_headers[csv_key]
      csv_records[record_key][db_headers[csv_key]] = csv_records[record_key].delete csv_headers[csv_key] if csv_records[record_key][csv_headers[csv_key]]
    end
  end
end

csv_records
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this row into you code, you have to clone your hash at first.

```
csv_records = csv_records.clone
```

This row will fix exactly only your problem with **ruby: can't add a new key into hash during iteration**

but it seams like your code not finished (*if you wanted to do it on your way*).
Your code with my fixes (*added one row*)

```
csv_records.each do |record_key,record_value|
  csv_headers.each do |csv_key,csv_value|
    if record_value.has_key? csv_value
      db_headers.each do |db_key, db_value|
        if csv_key == db_key
          csv_records = csv_records.clone
          csv_records[db_value] = csv_records.delete csv_value
          break
        end
      end
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!

Could you provide some information or explanation how does your solution solve the author's problem?

Comment: a changed answer to explain how to fix it